# Ajax function works on one page and does not work on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The following code is run when the page is load. it works on one page but when I use it on another pages for loading the feeds from different websites, it does not work. It is for RSSReader. I cannot understand why it works perfectly on one page but it does not work on another page.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>******</title>
</head>
<script>
function showRSSi() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==2) {
document.getElementById("artBody").innerHTML="loading....";
}
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
document.getElementById("artBody").innerHTML=this.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","RSS.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body onload="showRSSi();">
<div id="artBody">
</div>
</body>
</html>
Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: you support ie6 and ie5?

Comment: For more information RSS.php codes are here:

Comment: What does the devtools console output? `F12` --> `Console`

Comment: Try to change the URL to `/RSS.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if RSS.php lives in the root directory, that code will only work on the homepage and not on secondary pages. you can add a forward slash so your about page isn't looking for /about/RSS.php

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/RSS.php",true);
```

Comment: Thanks, All my files and pages  are in the root directory.  Do you think localhost can affect this??

Comment: @Peter localhost shouldn't be the problem. are you sure both pages have a <div id="artBody"> section? what do you see if you add this alert xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { alert(this.readyState+': '+this.status);

Comment: Nothing happens. Yes both has got artBody. it does not work on index.php. It is going to kill me

Comment: What I have noticed is whatever is written between <script></script> does not work on these pages?

Comment: @Peter if you add alert('testing'); inside the <script> tags does it work? do you have onload="showRSSi()" on your <body> tag?

Comment: @Peter Are you using something like turbolinks.js or pjax to switch between pages?

Comment: yes when I add alert(testing) inside of script, it works but just alert.  Yes I have onload on my body tag.  No I do not use turbolinks.js or pjax (I am very beginner in this area). It just doesnot work on index page. It works on all other pages.

Comment: Are you able to post the index.php somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Could I have an email from you?

Comment: saetia@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks It was fixed with your help.